# Why I receive the following message when linux ubuntu boot?

Tags: boot, kernel

When I try to boot Linux I receive this screen

[image: Error screen]

I changed the driver for video card in **Software and Updates** and I think that's the problem because that was the last thing I changed. I can enter recovery mode. What should I do?

Comment: Apparently the only solution was to reinstall the whole OS.